# Класс, который рисует на форме

Tags: c#, классы

Планирую сделать класс, в котором был бы метод, рисующий какой-либо объект на форме, допустим, прямоугольник. Но я не очень понимаю, как в классе задавать область рисования. Хочу потом на коде формы просто вызывать метод этого класса, что-то по типу:

```
Draw dr1 = new Draw ();
dr1.startDraw();
```

Начал писать класс, но как указать область рисования?:

```
class Draw
{

    public void startDraw()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(???.Width, ???.Height);
        Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        ???.Image = bmp;

    }
}
```

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса

Comment: @yolosora если бы я делал этот метод в коде, то мог бы вместо знаков вопроса поставить picturebox или экземпляр формы, а как  в классе указать, что нужно рисовать на форме?

Comment: В целом вопрос в том, как поправить код, чтобы при dr1.startDraw(); на форме рисовался прямоугольник

Comment: а, ну так передайте picturebox как аргумент

Comment: А как и где передать форму, я именно этот момент не понимаю

Comment: Я уже пробовал передать pictureBox1 вместо ???, но возникала ошибка, что он отсутствует в контексте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте метод с аргументом типа `PictureBox`. Вообще в таком случае можно статический метод сделать.

```
class Drawer
{
    public static void StartDraw(PictureBox pb)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pb.Width, pb.Height);
        Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        pb.Image = bmp;
    }
}
```

И так используйте потом в коде формы.

```
Drawer.StartDraw(this.pictureBox1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался!